# Problems with 'visited list' while using Dijkstras, Python

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, dijkstra, adjacency-list

I'm relatively new to coding so apologies for the overwritten, clumsy code.

Additionally f.f.r. this is from MIT's Open CourseWare "Problem Set 11, Fastest Way to Get Around MIT". (For later problem sets I can't find the solutions online..)

I have implemented a mostly-successful version of Dijkstra's algorithm with and without dynamic programming. In this implementation I'm keeping a list of nodes in order to avoid cycles/infinite loops...But to my understanding that's where I run into my problem. Given that my edges are weighted and in some cases I  would like to revisit the same NODES via different EDGES, this is leading to my code ignoring correct solutions. So I would like to find a way to modify my code such that it remembers which edges have been visited rather than which node and...I actually did try to modify it to remember which edges have been accessed - but my implementation did not work - so I'd love to see the correct way to write that.

An Example input that my code fails on:

```
# Test case 6
print "---------------"
print "Test case 6:"
print "Find the shortest-path from Building 1 to 32 without going outdoors"
expectedPath6 = ['1', '3', '10', '4', '12', '24', '34', '36', '32']
brutePath6 = bruteForceSearch(digraph, '1', '32', LARGE_DIST, 0)
dfsPath6 = directedDFS(digraph, '1', '32', LARGE_DIST, 0)
print "Expected: ", expectedPath6
print "Brute-force: ", brutePath6
print "DFS: ", dfsPath6
```

And the output from that code...

```
---------------
Test case 6:
Find the shortest-path from Building 1 to 32 without going outdoors
Expected:  ['1', '3', '10', '4', '12', '24', '34', '36', '32']
Brute-force:  ['1', '3', '10', '13', '24', '34', '36', '32']
DFS:  ['1', '3', '3', '3', '7', '7', '9', '13', '24', '34', '36', '36', '32']
```

Adjacency list is in the form of a dict within a dict, where the weights are stored as a tuple. To check the brute force code, the map input, or how the digraph is built go to this GitHub [here](https://github.com/GIimmer/MIT-6.00-PSet-11-Best-Path).

```
def findDist(digraph, start, path):
path = [str(start)] + path
distance = 0
outDistance = 0
for i in range(len(path)-1):
    edgeVals = None
    listOfDest = digraph.edges[Node(path[i])]
    for node in listOfDest:
        if node.has_key(Node(path[i+1])):
            edgeVals = node.values()
            distance = distance + edgeVals[0][0]
            outDistance = outDistance + edgeVals[0][1]
            break
return (distance, outDistance)

def directedDFS(digraph, start, end, maxTotalDist, maxDistOutdoors, toPrint = False, visited = [], level = 0, memo = {}):
"""
Finds the shortest path from start to end using directed depth-first.
search approach. The total distance travelled on the path must not
exceed maxTotalDist, and the distance spent outdoor on this path must
not exceed maxDisOutdoors.

Parameters: 
    digraph: instance of class Digraph or its subclass
    start, end: start & end building numbers (strings)
    maxTotalDist : maximum total distance on a path (integer)
    maxDistOutdoors: maximum distance spent outdoors on a path (integer)

Assumes:
    start and end are numbers for existing buildings in graph

Returns:
    The shortest-path from start to end, represented by 
    a list of building numbers (in strings), [n_1, n_2, ..., n_k], 
    where there exists an edge from n_i to n_(i+1) in digraph, 
    for all 1 <= i < k.

    If there exists no path that satisfies maxTotalDist and
    maxDistOutdoors constraints, then raises a ValueError.
"""
#TODO
if toPrint:
    print start, end
check = start
start = Node(start)
end = Node(end)
if not (digraph.hasNode(start) and digraph.hasNode(end)):
    raise ValueError('Start or end not in graph.')
path = [str(start)]
if start == end:
    return path
shortestDist = None
shortestOutDist = None
distFilter = (maxTotalDist <= maxDistOutdoors)
for child in digraph.childrenOf(start):
    childNode = child.keys()[0]
    if (str(childNode) not in visited):
        visited = visited + [str(childNode)]
        try:
            newPath = memo[start, end]
        except:
            newPath = directedDFS(digraph, str(childNode), str(end), maxTotalDist, maxDistOutdoors, toPrint, visited, level = level + 1)
        if newPath == None:
            continue
        newPathDist = findDist(digraph, start, newPath)
        if (distFilter) and (newPathDist[1] <= maxDistOutdoors) and ((shortestDist == None) or (newPathDist[0] < findDist(digraph, start, shortestDist)[0])):
            shortestDist = newPath
        elif (not distFilter) and ((shortestOutDist == None) or (newPathDist[1] <= findDist(digraph, start, shortestOutDist)[1])):
            if (shortestOutDist == None) or (newPathDist[0] <= findDist(digraph, start, shortestOutDist)[0]):
                shortestOutDist = newPath
                memo[childNode, end] = newPath
if (distFilter) and (shortestDist != None):
    path = path + shortestDist
elif (not distFilter) and (shortestOutDist != None):
    path = path + shortestOutDist
else: 
    path = None
if (level == 0) and (not distFilter) and (shortestOutDist == None):
    raise ValueError('No such path!')
elif (level == 0) and (not distFilter) and (findDist(digraph, start, shortestOutDist)[1] > maxDistOutdoors):
    raise ValueError('No such path!')
elif (level == 0) and (distFilter) and (shortestDist == None):
    raise ValueError('No such path!')
elif (level == 0) and (distFilter) and (findDist(digraph, start, shortestDist)[0] > maxTotalDist):
    raise ValueError('No such path!')
return path
```

Attached is an image of the expected result versus actual - ignore the last two as that's already solved. You can see test case 4 and 6 have the problems. [Code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJaFu.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Why does your code ignore correct solutions?

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant part of the output into the actual question. An image of text is never as useful as the text itself (unless it's a question about rendering text or something).

Comment: @Blckknght I added the test data which my solution fails on the most dramatically

Comment: @MxyL I'm not sure exactly what you mean, perhaps that's my problem - I can say that the edges have multiple weights (distance walked total, and distance walked outside), and for certain inputs the correct solution involves not only reaching the destination but also reaching the destination without walking outside. So the code throws away those solutions, ideally.

Comment: You should be able to walk through your code, given a specific case, and be able to say "this is why it's not walking along this edge and choosing a different edge". That should provide insights to which lines are suspect.

Comment: @MxyL I have done so; it's a little more of a hassle because of the levels of recursion...But that's on me. I can say that the code "skips over" the correct answer (node 24) when "start" is node 12.  This is because node 24 is already in the list of visited nodes by that point. I'm trying to think of an elegant way to not exclude nodes that have been visited if they can be accessed by a new edge...